# Converting higher order expression into alloy first order logic

Tags: logic, alloy, first-order-logic

I would like to write a bijection between a set and a relation in Alloy.

For example in the following code I would like to define ref to be a bijection between QArrow and event. Therefore, I write the fact **bij**. But Alloy complains, since I think I quantify over the relations which makes both expressions in the **bij** fact a higher order logic expression:

```
sig State {event : set State}
sig QArrow {ref: univ ->univ}

fact bij {
    all q:QArrow | one a: univ->univ | Q[a] and q.ref=a
    all a: univ->univ | one q:QArrow | Q[a] and q.ref=a
}

pred Q (a: univ->univ){
    a in event
}
```

How to convert these expression to be be first order logic expression?

Also, in general, is there any guideline when we can convert HOL expressions to FOL expression and when we can not do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this problem ( I posted the question in mathematical notation in the math satck exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073754/flattening-quantification-over-relations) and got the solution ) I am converting it to Alloy.

```
sig State {event : State}
sig QArrow{ref: State -> State}
fact {

        all q:univ | (q in QArrow implies (some s1,s2:univ | ( (s1->s2 in event) 
                            and (q.ref=s1->s2) and some s3,s4:univ | (( (s3->s4 in event) and  (q.ref=s3->s4) ) 
                            implies (s1->s2)=(s3->s4) ))))  // ref is a function

        all q1,q2,s1,s2:univ | (( (q1 in QArrow) and  (q2 in QArrow) and 
                (s1->s2 in event) and (q1.ref=s1->s2) and   (q2.ref=s1->s2)  ) implies q1=q2)   // ref is injective

        all s1,s2:univ | (some q:univ | (  ( s1->s2 in event) implies  
                                                ((q in QArrow) and (q.ref=s1->s2)) )) // ref is surjective
}
```

In above code the fact imposes **ref** to be a bijective function between **QArrow** and relation **event**.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to restric the domain of the quantified variables to their corresponding scope as bellow: (changing `univ` to `QArrow` for the elements of type `QArrow`, and changing `univ->univ` to `State ->State` for the pairs intended to be in `event` relation.

```
sig QArrow{ref: State -> State}
fact {

        all q:QArrow | (some s1,s2:State | ( (s1->s2 in event) 
                            and (q.ref=s1->s2) and some s3,s4:State | (( (s3->s4 in event) and  (q.ref=s3->s4) ) 
                            implies (s1->s2)=(s3->s4) )))  // ref is a function

        all q1,q2:QArrow, s1,s2:State | ((  (s1->s2 in event) and (q1.ref=s1->s2) and   (q2.ref=s1->s2)  ) implies q1=q2)   // ref is injective

        all s1,s2:State | (some q:QArrow | (  ( s1->s2 in event) implies  
                                                (q.ref=s1->s2) )) // ref is surjective

}
```